# Нужны ли запятые? Оборот с «согласно»

Tags: пунктуация

Согласно правилам MasterCard при проведении операций списания денежных средств с целью совершения переводов с карты на карту по технологии MasterCard MoneySend регламентировано применение MCC.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Обстоятельственные члены предложения, имеющие в своем составе производные предлоги и предложные сочетания (благодаря, согласно с, несмотря на и др.), обособляются при подчеркивании их смысла. Обороты с производными предлогами и предложными сочетаниями обязательно обособляются, если они располагаются между подлежащим и сказуемым: разрыв их непосредственной связи и способствует выделению оборотов. В других позициях такие обороты могут не обособляться (без необходимости подчеркивания). Сравните: Согласно приказу группа расформирована. — Группа, согласно приказу, расформирована (по В. В. Лопатину) 
В Вашем примере я бы не стала ставить запятую.

Answer (score 0):

В этом предложении можно обособить обстоятельство с предлогом ***согласно***: 
*Согласно правилам MasterCard, при проведении операций списания денежных средств...*

Кроме обстоятельств уступки, которые выделяются всегда, ***могут факультативно обособляться обстоятельства, выраженные существительными с производными предлогами БЛАГОДАРЯ, СОГЛАСНО, ВОПРЕКИ, ВВИДУ, ВСЛЕДСТВИЕ***, например: Благодаря хорошей погоде, мы купались в реке все лето. Обычно такие обстоятельства обособляются, если они распространены и стоят перед сказуемым. [Здесь](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_177) написано об этом.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно правилам MasterCard, / при проведении операций списания денежных средств /с целью совершения переводов с карты на карту/ по технологии MasterCard MoneySend/ **регламентировано применение MCC**.

**Запятую можно поставить и нужно поставить, но даже постановка запятой ненамного улучшит грамматическую форму предложения в части понимания его содержания**. Четыре обстоятельственных оборота (детерминанта) перед предикативной основой предложения - это, пожалуй, не самое удачное решение.

Хотя обособление обстоятельственных оборотов считается факультативным, в действительности на выбор решения влияют  **различные факторы**: позиция оборота, его распространенность, стиль речи. В данном случае **при препозиции обстоятельства и деловом стиле** обстоятельство чаще не обособляется, в то же время **распространенность** оборота способствует его обособлению.